# How to avoid necessity to put module prefix

Tags: coq

Before now I was editing IndProp.v file from Software foundations. But as soon as I put the code into a separate file I found that `eqb_neq` command requires a module prefix to work: `Nat.eqb_neq`.

Here is the code:

```
Set Warnings "-notation-overridden,-parsing".
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import PeanoNat.
Local Open Scope nat_scope.

Inductive nostutter {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
| ns_nil : nostutter []
| ns_one : forall (x : X), nostutter [x]
| ns_cons: forall (x : X) (h : X) (t : list X), nostutter (h::t) -> x <> h -> nostutter (x::h::t).

Example test_nostutter_1: nostutter [3;1;4;1;5;6].
Proof.
  repeat constructor; apply Nat.eqb_neq; auto.
Qed.
```

Is it possible to tell coq that I am always using Nat module here and get rid of `Nat` prefix? Like in C++ you can write `using namespace std;` and there will be no need to explicitly specify the namespace before every object from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Import Nat.` to do that. But this can harm readability sometimes. Some modules are designed to be used with their prefixes, e.g. stdlib's `Vector`.